# How to compute all permutations between a map of strings to ints

Tags: c++, permutation

Basically, I want to create all possible mappings of a vector of strings to a vector of ints.  I have the following:

```
std::vector<std::string> my_strings;
std::vector<unsigned int> my_ints;
my_strings.size() = 20; // not code, just for demonstration.
my_ints.size() = 4; // not code, just for demonstration.

std::vector<std::map<std::string, unsigned int> > all_possible_joint_mappings;
```

So, I want to populate `all_possible_joint_mappings` with all possible permutations of `my_strings` to `my_ints`.  What is a good way of accomplishing this?

An example joint mapping would be:

```
string_1 -> int_1
string_2 -> int_1
string_3 -> int_1
string_4 -> int_4
string_5 -> int_2
...
string_20 -> int_3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting the output to be, given what you've written.  I believe your join type should be a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> >` or a `std::multimap<std::string, unsigned int>`.

Comment: You need to define what the mappings are. Is every string going to be mapped to some int? Is each int going to have been mapped by some string? Something else?

Comment: @DaveS sorry, I've added an example permutation to the question.  I want to be able to quickly determine the mapped integer based on indexing the string, that's why a map was used.

Comment: Also above comment is for @bames53, but I can only notify one user at a time.

Comment: But it wouldn't be all possible mappings.  For instance, in your example, there are 4 integers, and 20 strings.  For all possible mappings, each string would be mapped to all 4 ints.  Which is why I suggested a multimap as a possible solution.

Comment: What you are describing is not a permutation. That would be a mapping of `string_1` ... `string_N` to `int_1` ... `int_N`.

Comment: @rhalbersma I want all permutations of that mapping.  All possible mappings.

Comment: is mapping all strings to int_1 a valid outcome then? or the first 10 to int_1 and the rest to int_2?

Comment: @rhalbersma that has to be valid, otherwise the mapping wouldn't make sense with more string than ints :)  Yes, all strings to int_1 is a valid mapping.

Comment: OK, so in your example, you want all 20-letter words from a 4-letter alphabet?

Comment: @rhalbersma Yeah, that's the gist of it.

Comment: I'm confused by the example joint mapping.  Why is `string_4` mapped to `int_4`, but no other strings are?  Why isn't it mapped to `int_1` like the rest?  Same questions for `string_5` and `string_20`.

Comment: @Chad because that's one possible permutation.  I want a vector of all possible permutations.  One possible permutation would be to assign all strings to int_1.  Another is to assign them all to int_4, or randomly assign like I've done above.

Comment: But, you want all permutations in a single container?

Comment: @zebra Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to iterate over one collection and in an inner loop, iterate over the other collection:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> > all_possible_joint_mappings;

for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator s = my_strings.begin(); s != my_strings.end(); ++s )
{
    for ( std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator i = my_ints.begin(); i != my_ints.end(); ++i )
        all_possible_joint_mappings.push_back( std::make_pair( *s, *i ) );
    }
}
```

Note, that the vector simply have to contain pairs to do the job.

kind regards
Torsten

Comment: use C++11 auto to eliminate ::iterator typing.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this just creates all possible pairs from string to int.  What I'm actually looking for is all possible mappings of _all_ strings to an int.  All possible permutations of that.

Comment: @rhalbersma sure, when C++11 compilers are widely available ;-)

Comment: Visual C++ express 2010, gcc 4.7 all free and suppporting `auto`

Comment: auto is available in a compiler near you.

Comment: @zebra I don't get it. What's the difference in you opinion?

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki Look at the mapping in my question.  That whole thing is one single mapping.  I want all permutations of that mapping (instead of string_1 -> int_1, map string_1 -> int_2/3/4, etc...)

Comment: @zebra, from this comment, I think you're asking for a `multimap`, see my answer (which details how to use one).

Comment: @zebra you've asked for 'all possible permutations of my_strings to my_ints'. So you have a vector of string/int tuples and want to have a permutation of all that tuples? If so, what roles to my_strings and my_ints play? If you want a permutation of a vector of string/int tuples (or pairs), you can use std::next_permutation after you've sorted that vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a mapping from each `string` value to multiple `int` values, and you want all permutations in a single container, then use a container type that is specifically designed for this purpose (`std::multimap`).  Here's an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> strings;
   std::vector<int> ints;

   strings.push_back("One");
   strings.push_back("Two");
   strings.push_back("Three");
   strings.push_back("Four");
   strings.push_back("Five");

   ints.push_back(1);
   ints.push_back(2);
   ints.push_back(3);

   typedef std::multimap<std::string, int> SIMAP;
   SIMAP string_to_ints;

   std::for_each(
      strings.cbegin(),
      strings.cend(),
      [&ints, &string_to_ints] (const std::string& s)
   {
      std::for_each(
         ints.cbegin(),
         ints.cend(),
         [&] (const int i)
      {
         string_to_ints.insert(std::make_pair(s,i));
      });
   });

   std::for_each(
      string_to_ints.cbegin(),
      string_to_ints.cend(),
      [] (const SIMAP::value_type& mapping)
   {
      std::cout
         << mapping.first << " -> " << mapping.second << "\n";
   });

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will recursively generate a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` of all 3-letter words (in lexicographic order), where each letter comes from a 4-letter alphabet. There are `64 = 4^3` such words.

Note that a simple double loop is not enough, you need to recurse over each of the letters in the words, and for each letter you need a loop. Total complexity is `O(K^N)` for `N`-letter words from a `K`-letter alphabet, and not `O(K*N)` as a double loop would.

It generalizes in a straightfoward way to 20-letter words from a 4-letter alphabet (although that is 2^40 = 1e12 different words). To match those to your original string is a straightforward manner of course.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int K, int N>
void generate_all_multisets(
    std::array<T, K> const& alphabet, 
    std::vector< std::vector<T> >& all_words, 
    std::vector<T>& current_word, 
    int current_letter
)
{
    if (current_letter == N) {
        all_words.push_back(current_word);
        for (auto k = 0; k != N; ++k) 
            std::cout << current_word[k];
        std::cout << "\n";
        return;
    }   

    auto const tmp = current_word[current_letter];
    for (auto letter = alphabet.begin(); letter != alphabet.end(); ++letter) {
        current_word[current_letter] = *letter;
        generate_all_multisets<T, K, N>(alphabet, all_words, current_word, current_letter + 1);
    }
    current_word[current_letter] = tmp; 
}

template<typename T, int K, int N>
void generate_all_words(
    std::array<T, K> const& alphabet, 
    std::vector< std::vector<T> >& all_words
)
{
    // first word
    std::vector<T> word(N, alphabet.front());
    generate_all_multisets<T, K, N>(alphabet, all_words, word, 0);
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> alphabet = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto const word_length = 3; 

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > all_words;
    generate_all_words<int, 4, 3>(alphabet, all_words);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/G3dLR)